# Mongo Facet Aggregation with Sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to figure out something simple in this aggregation.  The field "totalArrests" under metadata is coming back 0.  It's not able to sum this field from the previous stage for some reason. Please advise.

```
const agg = await KID.aggregate([
        { 
            $group: {
                _id: "$source", // group by this
                title: { "$last": "$title"},
                comments: { "$last": "$comments"},
                body: { "$last": "$body"},
                date: { "$last": "$date"},
                media: { "$last": "$media"},
                source: { "$last": "$source"},
                count: { "$sum": 1},
                arrestCount: { "$sum": "$arrested"},
                rescuedCount: { "$sum": "$rescued"},
            }
        },
        // sorting
        {
            $sort: {date: sort}
        },
        // facets for paging
        {
            $facet: {
                metadata: [ 
                    { $count: "total" },  // Returns a count of the number of documents at this stage
                    { $addFields: { 
                        page: page, 
                        limit: 30,
                        totalArrests: {$sum: "$arrestCount"}
                    }},
                ],
                kids: [ { $skip: (page-1)*30 }, { $limit: 30 } ]
            }
        },
    ]);
```

Here is a sample document in the collection.

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e8b922aaf5ccf5ac588398c,
    counter: 4,
    date: 2017-01-01T17:00:00.000Z,
    name: 'Steven Tucker',
    arrested: 1,
    rescued: 0,
    country: 'US',
    state: 'NH',
    comments: 'Sex trafficking of a minor',
    source: 'https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/new-hampshire-man-indicted-sex-trafficking-minor-connection-interstate-prostitution',
    title: 'New ....',
    body: 'Steven Tucker, 31, ....',
    __v: 0,
    media: {
      title: 'New Hampshire Man Indicted for Sex ...',
      open_graph: [Object],
      twitter_card: [Object],
      favicon: 'https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/favicon.png'
    },
    id: 5e8b922aaf5ccf5ac588398c,
    text: 'New Hampshire Man Indicted',
    utcDate: '2017-01-01T12:00'
  }
]
```

Comment: Can't guess from the above query. Show some documents to reproduce the output.

Comment: @Ashh added a sample document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$count` will only provide you the count for number of documents and escapes all the other things.

So, You have to use one more pipeline in `$facet` in order to get the documents.

```
{ $facet: {
  metadata: [
    { $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: 1 },
      totalArrested: { $sum: "$arrestCount" }
    }},
    { $project: {
      total: 1,
      totalArrested: 1,
      page: page,
      limit: 30,
      hasMore: { $gt: [{ $ceil: { $divide: ["$total", 30] }}, page] }
    }}
  ],
  kids: [{ $skip: (page-1) * 30 }, { $limit: 30 }]
}}
```

Comment: Very nice.  I had to use AddFields to make it work.

{ $addFields: {
      page: page,
      limit: 30,
      hasMore: { $gt: [{ $ceil: { $divide: ["$total", 30] }}, page] }
     }},
     { $project: {
      total: 1,
      totalArrested: 1,
      totalRescued: 1,
      page: 1,
      limit: 1,
      hasMore: 1,
     }}

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
    cost:1
    },
  },

  {
    $facet: {
      metadata: [
        {
          $count: "total",
        },
      ],

      data: [],
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      metadata: "$metadata",
      totalcostall: { $sum: "$data.cost" },
      result: "$data",
    },
  },
]);
```