# How do I get projection and and aggregation of the documents in different objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to return the matching documents in such a way that their _id and status gets added to an object `result` and their aggregation ($sum) gets added to another object called `aggregate`. The documents look like this -
Document 1:

```
{
_id: 5efbd2ffc93f2352ad91666e,
varId: 'KL63D4280',
status: 'completed',
collection: 40,
cash: 3,
upi: 6000,
driverSalary: 4
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
_id: 5efbd2ffc93f2352ad916672,
varId: 'KL63D4280',
status: 'completed',
collection: 5,
cash: 3,
upi: 187,
driverSalary: 3
}
```

The output should look like the following :

```
{
  result: [
    {
      _id: 5efbd2ffc93f2352ad91666e,
      varId: 'KL63D4280',
      status: 'completed'
    },
    {
      _id: 5efbd2ffc93f2352ad916672,
      varId: 'KL63D4280',
      status: 'completed'
    }
  ],
  aggregates: {
    _count: 2,
    collection: 45,
    cash: 6,
    upi: 6187,
    driverSalary: 7,
 }
}
```

My code looks is like the below but it doesn't give the right output and looks like it would take much time -

```
const res = await BusDayWiseBreakDown.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        varId,
        status
      }
    },
    {
      $facet: {
        result: [
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              varId:1,
              status:1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $facet: {
        aggregates: [
          {
            $project: {
             _count: 1,
            collection: 1,
            cash: 1,
            upi: 1,
            driverSalary: 1,
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: null,
            collection: { $sum: "$collection" },
            cash: { $sum: "$cash" },
            upi: { $sum: "$upi" },
            driverSalary: { $sum: "$driverSalary" },
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]).session(mongoSession);

  return res; 
  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo Facet Aggregation with Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530983/mongo-facet-aggregation-with-sum)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways this could be done.  Here's one way.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      varId: "KL63D4280",
      status: "completed"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "results": {
        "$push": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "varId": "$varId",
          "status": "$status"
        }
      },
      "_count": {"$count": {}},
      "collection": {"$sum": "$collection"},
      "cash": {"$sum": "$cash"},
      "upi": {"$sum": "$upi"},
      "driverSalary": {"$sum": "$driverSalary"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "results": 1,
      "aggregates": {
        "_count": "$_count",
        "collection": "$collection",
        "cash": "$cash",
        "upi": "$upi",
        "driverSalary": "$driverSalary"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/46YnMipOS4L).